Anki: How to match using both w: and nc:?
From the Anki documentation:

use w:foo to match word boundaries, like \bfoo\b
use nc:foo to match ignoring accents e.g. nc:uber matches über.

Is it possible to combine both?
Example use case: to match für (thinking of the German word).
None of the following works: w:nc:fur, nc:w:fur.

Update Anki Settings: Preferences > Editing > "Ignore accents in search (slower)".
Now search with w:, such as w:fur.
